# Can't display popup after click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display popup when 'Propose' button is clicked.

TestPopUp.tsx

```
const TestPopUp = () => {
  return (
    <div>
     <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestPopUp;
```

CandidateActions.tsx

```
import  TestPopUp  from '../../TestPopUp';

  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

   return (
<>
  <ActionsGroup
    actionsData={[
      {
        title: 'Propose',
        onHandleClick: () => {     
          setShowPopup(true);
        },
      },
      {
        title: 'Skills',
        onHandleClick: () => {
          setSkillsModalOpen(true);
        },
      },
    ]}
  />
  { showPopup && <TestPopUp /> }
  <CandidateSkillsModal
    candidate={candidate}
    isOpen={skillsModalOpen}
    onClose={() => {
      setSkillsModalOpen(false);
      setShowPopup(true);
    }}
    
  />
</>
  );
    };

export default CandidateActions;
```

Additional notes : alert "Propose clicked, setting showPopup to true" is displayed.
as for logging showPopUp : [image]
Don't know why true and false are displayed many times. There are no errors, only popup isn't displayed

Comment: you have written **console.log(showPopup);** which is store boolean value

Comment: after click use the condition {showPopup && (<TestPopUp /> )}

Answer (score 1):

> only popup isn't displayed

You're not actually displaying it anywhere.  You do have this random line of JSX in the middle of a function:

```
<TestPopUp />
```

Which does nothing.  *Outside* of that function, in the overall markup, is where you'd put your markup.  For example, something like this:

```
<ActionsGroup
  ... your existing code, mostly
/>

{ showPopup && <TestPopUp /> }

<CandidateSkillsModal
  candidate={candidate}
  isOpen={skillsModalOpen}
  onClose={() => {
    setSkillsModalOpen(false);
  }}
/>
```

Basically, the click handler function doesn't try to forcibly display the element.  The function just *updates state*.  The element is conditionally displayed based on that state.

Comment: Tried it but no result. 
'<ActionsGroup actionsData={[{...}, {...} ]} />  { showPopup && <TestPopUp /> }'

Comment: @GugaTodua: Can you update the question to show what you tried?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: removed extra code. updated the code in my question

Comment: @GugaTodua: And how have you confirmed that state is being updated?  Can you provide a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) (or, failing that, at least something off-site that's runnable, such as on Code Sandbox) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sorry. Difficult to reproduce an example since I barely understand how JS and React work. I only picked up this task because we ran out of FE devs :)

Comment: @GugaTodua: That makes it increasingly likely that you have made another mistake in the code, perhaps not shown here.  The original problem was also pretty indicative of a lack of understanding of how React works.  We can sympathize with that, but at this point it sounds like your next step is to start with some tutorials on React and begin learning that tool.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  inside anywhere in random line of jsx format.

```
 // inside return component
....your rest code here
{ showPopup && <TestPopUp /> }
....your rest code here
```

Comment: Tried adding that line inside return, but no result

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).